# Query joining four tables resulting in one row

Tags: join, mariadb, mariadb-10.3

I have these two queries which pull data from four tables:

```
select files.id, files.name, dirs.dir
from files
inner join dirs on dirs.id = files.idDir
where files.id = 45

select label
from labels
inner join labels_files on labels_files.idLabel = labels.id
where labels_files.idFile = 45
```

The first query returns 1 row.
The second query return 1 or more row/s

My goal is to get one query and one row on the resultset.
Say:

```
--------------------------------------------------
45 | test.txt  |  /home  | label1, label2, labeln |
--------------------------------------------------
```

I guess I should try derived tables, but been trying to no avail.

Answer (score 5):

You need to join the tables from both queries and then use `GROUP_CONCAT()` to concatenate the labels:

(the query assumes that `files (id)` is `UNIQUE` or the PRIMARY KEY`)

```
select
    files.id, files.name, dirs.dir,
    group_concat( labels.label
                  order by labels.label
                  separator ', '
                ) as label_list
from
    files
  inner join dirs
    on dirs.id = files.idDir
  inner join labels_files
    on labels_files.idFile = files.id  
  inner join labels
    on labels_files.idLabel = labels.id
where
    files.id = 45
group by
    files.id,
    dirs.dir ;
```

Comment: Thank you so much ypercube. This is exactly what I was looking for.
And this, though, made me wonder why the order of the inner joins are important. I tried altering the order and got undesired results. Regards!

Comment: The order of joins is not important in this query (as it has only inner joins). If you got different results, you probably  changed or omitted some condition.